# numpy eigenvalues correct but eigenvectors wrong

Tags: python, numpy

My code is

```
print numpy.linalg.eig([[1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 9], [63, 7, 5]])
```

The output is

(array([ 21.61455381,  -9.76720959,  -1.84734422]), array([[-0.17186028, -0.14352001,  0.03651047],
   [-0.48646994, -0.50447076, -0.8471429 ],
   [-0.85662772,  0.8514172 ,  0.53010931]]))

I am using an online eigenvector calcualtor to verify http://www.arndt-bruenner.de/mathe/scripts/engl_eigenwert2.htm
which gives the following answer:

Real Eigenvalues:   { -9.767209588804548 ;  -1.8473442163236111 ;  21.61455380512816 }

Eigenvectors:

for Eigenvalue -9.767209588804548:
   [ -0.1685660264358372 ; -0.5925071319066865 ; 1 ]

for Eigenvalue -1.8473442163236111:
   [ 0.06887346700751434 ; -1.5980532339710003 ; 1 ]

for Eigenvalue 21.61455380512816:
   [ 0.20062423644695662 ; 0.5678895584242702 ; 1 ]

The values obviously don't match. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Actually the eigenvectors are correct, but the presentation is somewhat confusing. If the output of `eig` is

> (array([1, 2, 3]), array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 6, -5], [1, -3, 0]]))

that is not saying that the eigenvectors are [1, 2, 3], [4, 6, -5], and [1, -3, 0]. Rather, those are the rows in a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors:

```
[1  2  3]
[4  6 -5]
[1 -3  0]
```

So in this made-up example, the eigenvectors would be [1, 4, 1], [2, 6, -3], and [3, -5, 0], corresponding to eigenvalues 1, 2, and 3, respectively. Note that I made up these numbers so they may not make sense mathematically for any matrix.

Comment: I think this is important. This can be initially confusing.

Answer (score 3):

They do match (sort of...).

These eigenvectors are indeed the same as one another, however the ones from the online calculator are not normalized (though they probably should be for the sake of convenience). The eigenvectors of a matrix can be scaled by any scalar (a number) and still be the eigenvectors, so this is not incorrect, however the convention is often to keep them normalized, since it is more convenient for other operations. A quick check with MATLAB (an independent source) shows that the eigenvalues of match exactly the ones returned by numpy.

You will notice that the numpy vectors satisfy the property that `norm(eigenvector)=1`. If you were to normalize the vectors from the online calculator so that

```
eigenvector <- eigenvector/norm(eigenvector)
```

you will see that they match.

Comment: Actually the value of the norm is coming out 1.732

Comment: That's the point. Divide each element of the vector by its norm and then look at the result; it will match the numpy result.